# Move from to a specific tab in another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, bootstrap-tabs

I have this code:

```
<ul id="tabsss">
    <li  class="underUl"> <a href="about.php#History"> - History</a></li>
    <li  class="underUl"><a href="about.php#Concept"> - The Concept</a></li>
    <li  id="cst1" class="underUl"><a href="about.php#Choose_CST"> - Why Choose CST?</a></li>
    <li  id="management1" class="underUl">- Management</li>
    <li   id="department1" class="underUl">- Department</li>
</ul>
```

In another page I have these `<div>`

```
<div class="tab-pane active"  id="History">test</div>
<div class="tab-pane"  id="Concept">test1</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="Choose_CST">ssss</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="Management">ssss</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="Department">ssss</div>
```

I want to go to the specific tab in the other page. Right now it's only opening the first one only.

Aany help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understood it correctly you want to scroll to a specific element on the initial page load?

Comment: no i need to go a specific element in other page.. @DavidePerozzi

Comment: So your tab-pane elements are placed on the about.php page? If so, the hash suffix should do the trick. So "about.php#History" will scroll to the element with the id "History". Make sure the element is rendered correctly and is visible, also the id doesn't appear more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I read your question again, it can be easily achieved using JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  url_params = window.location.hash;  
  tabParams = $('a[href="' + url_params + '"]');
  console.log(tabParams);
  console.log(url_params);
  if (tabParams.length === 0) 
  {
  //Activate first tab
  //Show first tab content
  } 
  else 
  {
    tabParams.click();
  }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add some javascript when loading the second page.

Something like :

```
if (window.location.hash == "History"){
   $('.tab').hide(); //hide all other tabs
   $('#History').show();
}
```

If you have your tabs on the about page, it could be done like this :

```
var currentTab = window.location.hash;
$('a[href="#'+currentTab+'"]').tab('show');
```